# Error removing entry and freeing bucket node in C linked list traversal

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list, free, traversal

I am trying to develop a Hash Table with chained linked-list hashing to remedy collisions, but I seem to be having an error with my remove_entry function. I am working almost exclusively with pointers, and as such I am dynamically allocation and freeing memory as necessary.

Here are the structures for my Table and Bucket datatypes:

```
typedef struct bucket {
char *key;
void *value;
struct bucket *next;
} Bucket;

typedef struct {
   int key_count;
   int table_size;
   void (*free_value)(void *);
   Bucket **buckets;
} Table;
```

And here is my remove function. I tried to include commentary to explain what is going on:

```
int remove_entry(Table *table, const char *key) {

    int hash;
    Bucket *cur, *prev;

    if (table == NULL || key == NULL) {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    hash = hash_code(key) % (table->table_size);

    /* case: key not present at lead bucket position */
    if (table->buckets[hash] == NULL) {
        return FAILURE;

    } else {
        cur = table->buckets[hash];
        /* traverse thru the chain from table->buckets[hash]
         * to see if the key exists somewhere. loop only can run the 
         * first time if its key does not match the paramteter key, so
         * if they do match then we proceed to the logic below this
         * loop (2nd if statement), acting on the FIRST (lead) bucket */
        while (strcmp(cur->key, key) != 0 && cur != NULL) {
            prev = cur;
            cur = cur->next;
        }

        /* case - key not found anywhere (cur == null) */
        if (cur == NULL) {
            return FAILURE;
        }
        /* case - key found in chain (strcmp returned 0, keys match) */
        if (strcmp(cur->key, key) == 0) {
            if (table->free_value != NULL) {
                table->free_value(cur->value);
                cur->value = NULL;
            }
            free(cur->key);
            cur->key = NULL;
            if (cur->next != NULL) {
                prev->next = cur->next;
            }
            free(cur);
            cur = NULL;
            table->key_count -= 1;
            return SUCCESS;
        }
    }
    return FAILURE;
}
```

valgrind tells me that there is an issue calling free() on cur at the bottom of the function, but I don't understand why that's an issue. The overall issue I found I am having is that the address of the bucket (at the appropriate index "hash") undergoes no change even though cur is changed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, though it's a small point, SUCCESS is #define 'd as 1 and FAILURE is #define 'd as -1

Answer (score 0):

I think your error involves removing the FIRST *bucket* when more that one *bucket* exists.

In this code segment:

```
 cur = table->buckets[hash];
 while (strcmp(cur->key, key) != 0 && cur != NULL) {
     prev = cur;
     cur = cur->next;
 }
```

If *key* does indeed equal the FIRST *bucket* pointed to by the *cur* pointer then your WHILE loop's inner code never gets invoked.  And the upshot is that pointer *prev* is undefined ... you never pre-set it to NULL and it did not get set in that bypassed loop.

So this subsequent code snippet:

```
if (cur->next != NULL) {
    prev->next = cur->next;
}
```

is going to fail since *prev* has either zero (NULL) in it, or has some undefined memory location stored in it.

Also the logic of the above code snippet is not quite correct; if this is the last *bucket* being removed (so *cur->next* indeed equals NULL), you still want to move that NULL back into the *prev->next* (or the list head) so that *prev* "knows" it is now the end of the linked list.

You are also failing to account for the case that you need to reset you linked list header (and not *prev->next*) when the very first *bucket* is the one being removed.  This is a common mistake, and one I've answered several times recently just this week.

So I think you need to change your code to:

```
int remove_entry(Table *table, const char *key) {

    int hash;
    Bucket *cur;
    Bucket *prev = NULL;

    if (table == NULL || key == NULL) {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    hash = hash_code(key) % (table->table_size);

    /* case: key not present at lead bucket position */
    if (table->buckets[hash] == NULL) {
        return FAILURE;

    } else {
        cur = table->buckets[hash];
        /* traverse thru the chain from table->buckets[hash]
         * to see if the key exists somewhere. loop only can run the 
         * first time if its key does not match the paramteter key, so
         * if they do match then we proceed to the logic below this
         * loop (2nd if statement), acting on the FIRST (lead) bucket */
        while (strcmp(cur->key, key) != 0 && cur != NULL) {
            prev = cur;
            cur = cur->next;
        }

        /* case - key not found anywhere (cur == null) */
        if (cur == NULL) {
            return FAILURE;
        }
        /* case - key found in chain (strcmp returned 0, keys match) */
        if (strcmp(cur->key, key) == 0) {
            if (table->free_value != NULL) {
                table->free_value(cur->value);
                cur->value = NULL;
            }
            free(cur->key);
            cur->key = NULL;
            if (prev != NULL) {
                prev->next = cur->next;  // even want to copy-back when cur->next == NULL
            }
            else
            {
                table->buckets[hash] = cur->next;  // even want to copy-back when cur->next == NULL
            }
            free(cur);
            cur = NULL;
            table->key_count -= 1;
            return SUCCESS;
        }
    }
    return FAILURE;
}
```

I'm not sure why *free(cur)* would be giving you an error, but once you've fixed up the code to handle the linked list properly and don't have a *prev* pointer that is not properly initialized, you may be able to figure out what remains wrong.

One other trivial nit, you really don't need the following standalone IF statement: *if (strcmp(cur->key, key) == 0) {*.  When you exit the WHILE loop, the only two conditions are *cur* indeed == NULL, or *strcmp(cur->key, key)* indeed == 0.  You do not need the second IF statement.  Its not wrong, just slightly inefficient.